# bootstrap popover by hover in image picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to put [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and [Image Picker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) together.

The image picker function turn select in html into image and allow users to select.
The problem is that I dont have the code of image in html so I cannot add the popover thing in it.

How do I change javascript of the image picker so that when users hover over the div or the image, bootstrap popover will show? And when I leave the div / image, the popover will disappear.

I have over 10 image and each of them have different text.
The code of image is created by the function, but i do not understand the code in the function

**JavaScript of Image Picker:**

```
(function() {
  var ImagePicker, ImagePickerOption, both_array_are_equal, sanitized_options,
    __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    __indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    imagepicker: function(opts) {
      if (opts == null) {
        opts = {};
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var select;
        select = jQuery(this);
        if (select.data("picker")) {
          select.data("picker").destroy();
        }
        select.data("picker", new ImagePicker(this, sanitized_options(opts)));
        if (opts.initialized != null) {
          return opts.initialized.call(select.data("picker"));
        }
      });
    }
  });

  sanitized_options = function(opts) {
    var default_options;
    default_options = {
      hide_select: true,
      show_label: false,
      initialized: void 0,
      changed: void 0,
      clicked: void 0,
      selected: void 0,
      limit: void 0,
      limit_reached: void 0
    };
    return jQuery.extend(default_options, opts);
  };

  both_array_are_equal = function(a, b) {
    return jQuery(a).not(b).length === 0 && jQuery(b).not(a).length === 0;
  };

  ImagePicker = (function() {

    function ImagePicker(select_element, opts) {
      this.opts = opts != null ? opts : {};
      this.sync_picker_with_select = __bind(this.sync_picker_with_select, this);

      this.select = jQuery(select_element);
      this.multiple = this.select.attr("multiple") === "multiple";
      if (this.select.data("limit") != null) {
        this.opts.limit = parseInt(this.select.data("limit"));
      }
      this.build_and_append_picker();
    }

    ImagePicker.prototype.destroy = function() {
      var option, _i, _len, _ref;
      _ref = this.picker_options;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        option = _ref[_i];
        option.destroy();
      }
      this.picker.remove();
      this.select.unbind("change");
      this.select.removeData("picker");
      return this.select.show();
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.build_and_append_picker = function() {
      var _this = this;
      if (this.opts.hide_select) {
        this.select.hide();
      }
      this.select.change(function() {
        return _this.sync_picker_with_select();
      });
      if (this.picker != null) {
        this.picker.remove();
      }
      this.create_picker();
      this.select.after(this.picker);
      return this.sync_picker_with_select();
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.sync_picker_with_select = function() {
      var option, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
      _ref = this.picker_options;
      _results = [];
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        option = _ref[_i];
        if (option.is_selected()) {
          _results.push(option.mark_as_selected());
        } else {
          _results.push(option.unmark_as_selected());
        }
      }
      return _results;
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.create_picker = function() {
      this.picker = jQuery("<ul class='thumbnails image_picker_selector'></ul>");
      this.picker_options = [];
      this.recursively_parse_option_groups(this.select, this.picker);
      return this.picker;
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.recursively_parse_option_groups = function(scoped_dom, target_container) {
      var container, option, option_group, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref, _ref1, _results;
      _ref = scoped_dom.children("optgroup");
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        option_group = _ref[_i];
        option_group = jQuery(option_group);
        container = jQuery("<ul></ul>");
        container.append(jQuery("<li class='group_title'>" + (option_group.attr("label")) + "</li>"));
        target_container.append(jQuery("<li>").append(container));
        this.recursively_parse_option_groups(option_group, container);
      }
      _ref1 = (function() {
        var _k, _len1, _ref1, _results1;
        _ref1 = scoped_dom.children("option");
        _results1 = [];
        for (_k = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _k < _len1; _k++) {
          option = _ref1[_k];
          _results1.push(new ImagePickerOption(option, this, this.opts));
        }
        return _results1;
      }).call(this);
      _results = [];
      for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
        option = _ref1[_j];
        this.picker_options.push(option);
        if (!option.has_image()) {
          continue;
        }
        _results.push(target_container.append(option.node));
      }
      return _results;
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.has_implicit_blanks = function() {
      var option;
      return ((function() {
        var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
        _ref = this.picker_options;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          option = _ref[_i];
          if (option.is_blank() && !option.has_image()) {
            _results.push(option);
          }
        }
        return _results;
      }).call(this)).length > 0;
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.selected_values = function() {
      if (this.multiple) {
        return this.select.val() || [];
      } else {
        return [this.select.val()];
      }
    };

    ImagePicker.prototype.toggle = function(imagepicker_option) {
      var new_values, old_values, selected_value;
      old_values = this.selected_values();
      selected_value = imagepicker_option.value().toString();
      if (this.multiple) {
        if (__indexOf.call(this.selected_values(), selected_value) >= 0) {
          new_values = this.selected_values();
          new_values.splice(jQuery.inArray(selected_value, old_values), 1);
          this.select.val([]);
          this.select.val(new_values);
        } else {
          if ((this.opts.limit != null) && this.selected_values().length >= this.opts.limit) {
            if (this.opts.limit_reached != null) {
              this.opts.limit_reached.call(this.select);
            }
          } else {
            this.select.val(this.selected_values().concat(selected_value));
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.has_implicit_blanks() && imagepicker_option.is_selected()) {
          this.select.val("");
        } else {
          this.select.val(selected_value);
        }
      }
      if (!both_array_are_equal(old_values, this.selected_values())) {
        this.select.change();
        if (this.opts.changed != null) {
          return this.opts.changed.call(this.select, old_values, this.selected_values());
        }
      }
    };

    return ImagePicker;

  })();

  ImagePickerOption = (function() {

    function ImagePickerOption(option_element, picker, opts) {
      this.picker = picker;
      this.opts = opts != null ? opts : {};
      this.clicked = __bind(this.clicked, this);

      this.option = jQuery(option_element);
      this.create_node();
    }

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.destroy = function() {
      return this.node.find(".thumbnail").unbind();
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.has_image = function() {
      return this.option.data("img-src") != null;
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.is_blank = function() {
      return !((this.value() != null) && this.value() !== "");
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.is_selected = function() {
      var select_value;
      select_value = this.picker.select.val();
      if (this.picker.multiple) {
        return jQuery.inArray(this.value(), select_value) >= 0;
      } else {
        return this.value() === select_value;
      }
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.mark_as_selected = function() {
      return this.node.find(".thumbnail").addClass("selected");
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.unmark_as_selected = function() {
      return this.node.find(".thumbnail").removeClass("selected");
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.value = function() {
      return this.option.val();
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.label = function() {
      if (this.option.data("img-label")) {
        return this.option.data("img-label");
      } else {
        return this.option.text();
      }
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.clicked = function() {
      this.picker.toggle(this);
      if (this.opts.clicked != null) {
        this.opts.clicked.call(this.picker.select, this);
      }
      if ((this.opts.selected != null) && this.is_selected()) {
        return this.opts.selected.call(this.picker.select, this);
      }
    };

    ImagePickerOption.prototype.create_node = function() {
      var image, thumbnail;
      this.node = jQuery("<li/>");
      image = jQuery("<img class='image_picker_image'/>");
      image.attr("src", this.option.data("img-src"));
      thumbnail = jQuery("<div class='thumbnail'>");
      thumbnail.click({
        option: this
      }, function(event) {
        return event.data.option.clicked();
      });
      thumbnail.append(image);
      if (this.opts.show_label) {
        thumbnail.append(jQuery("<p/>").html(this.label()));
      }
      this.node.append(thumbnail);
      return this.node;
    };

    return ImagePickerOption;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think you are over-thinking this.  Instead of changing the image-picker library, use javascript to add the popovers after the thumbnails have been rendered.

Comment: But the div and the img do not have id, but each image has different text in the popover. Cant use javascript to add popover. Is there anyother way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand more what you are looking for.  Unfortunately I think you are going to have to use javascript to apply the pop-over because this elements are added to the DOM dynamically.

With one line of code you can add an ID to each image:

```
...
    ImagePickerOption.prototype.create_node = function() {
      var image, thumbnail;
      this.node = jQuery("<li/>");
      image = jQuery("<img class='image_picker_image'/>");
      image.attr("src", this.option.data("img-src"));

      //**ADD THIS LINE**
      image.attr("id", this.option.data("img-id"));
      //*****************

      thumbnail = jQuery("<div class='thumbnail'>");
      thumbnail.click({
        option: this
      }, function(event) {
        return event.data.option.clicked();
      });
      thumbnail.append(image);
      if (this.opts.show_label) {
        thumbnail.append(jQuery("<p/>").html(this.label()));
      }
      this.node.append(thumbnail);
      return this.node;
    };
...
```

In you options tag you can now do:

```
<option
  data-img-src='http://www.example.com/image.jpg'
  data-img-id='picture1'>
```

This will allow you do add the popover through javascript like so:

```
$('#picture1').popover({ content: 'Picture 1 Message' });
```

**Important Note:**  Use the I imagepicker initialized callback method to apply your popovers, this will ensure your elements exist on the DOM.